# Code working in XCode 6.1 not working in XCode 6.3

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

If I write a code to navigate from one `UIViewController` to another in my Xcode then it will give me the error " Unknown class xxx in Interface Builder file ".

But if I do the same code or take the same project file and clean build and run in the next mac it will run, with out any problem. Take the project file back to my PC, and it is working fine in my PC to.

I have tried uninstalling and installing the latest beta version of the Xcode and resting and simulator and restarting the PC several times. But but no change in the error for the code I wrote using my Xcode.

***How can I code on my pc or make my pc run the code I write in my own pc, without running on the other pc and taking it back.***

**I am using :-
 os x 10.10.2 ,
xcode 6.3**

Thank you.

Comment: Was my answer satisfying or are you looking for something else?

Comment: no actually my problem is i can't code in swift in my xcode, exactlly i can write a code which will take me from one view controller to another.(navigating from one uiviewcontroller to another uiviewcontroller using uistoryboard.) hope you will excuse my late reply to this comment and expecting a help soon.

Answer (score 1):

Apple shipped Swift 1.2 with Xcode 6.3. See https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=22

They've also added a migration tool:

> Swift 1.2 is a major step forward for both the language and the tools.
>   It does include some source-incompatible changes that require updates
>   to your code, so Xcode 6.3 includes a migrator to help automate the
>   process. To begin the migration, click the Edit menu, then choose
>   Convert > To Swift 1.2...

As for now, 6.3 is still beta.

Hope it helps :)